# undefined reference to FOLDERID_.. - C++

Tags: c++, winapi

compiling c++ from linux to windows using **g++** and got an error.

**Error:**

```
undefined reference to `FOLDERID_RoamingTiles'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm guessing there is a library I have to reference but I don't know what the name is.

also if that's the case what are the ways I could find the name of the library I have to reference, if that happens again in the future?

thanks.

Comment: In the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid at  the very end of the document, you'll see the header file: Knownfolders.h (the full path with the Windows SDK is something like %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\KnownFolders.h)

Comment: yes I already included this header file with no results, I was thinking something like the -l option in g++?

Comment: You'll want to `#define INITGUID` or `#define INITKNOWNFOLDERS` prior to including *KnownFolders.h*. If neither preprocessor symbol is defined, the *KnownFolders.h* header merely declares the `GUID`s, but doesn't define them, which eventually leads to the linker error you observed.

Comment: alright, that seemed to have worked but now i discover that mingw requires some dll to run on windows, anyways I think that is unrelated. thanks anyways :)

Comment: They're exported from libuuid. Linking to `-luuid` would be the "right" way rather than defining the init symbols (although that's a plan B). If you don't have libuuid you'll have to do a little digging; hard to answer without knowing more details about platform (for example some Qt and MinGW install configurations will have it, some won't, etc.)

Comment: I would like to reinforce the question of the author: "What are the ways I could find the name of the library I have to reference?" I could not find anything in the Microsoft docs, only the requirement of the header file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm compiling under msys2/gcc. linking to uuid helped me.

```
g++ -luuid -o ....
```